# How can I handle and get rid of the loading screen at the top of the stack widget when main content is loaded using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a scaffold that has a Google Map widget inside it. I am trying to fetch some data from a web service, initialize some variables and then when map is created and page is ready, I am setting my "loadingStatus" variable to "LoadingStatus.done" to show the page to the user.

While the page is loading, (loadingStatus is LoadingStatus.loading), I am showing to user a basic loading screen.

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    MapBody(),  
    LoadingBody()
  ],
);
```

When loading is done, opacity of the Loading widget is set to 0 and I am ignoring clicks to that widget so that user can click on the widget at the bottom of the stack. Problem is, this LoadingBody widget is still there, at the top of the stack, using device resources.

```
Widget LoadingBody(){

    return IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.loading ? false : true,
      child: AnimatedOpacity(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        opacity: loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.loading ? 1 : 0,
        child: Container(
          color: chargeDarkGrey,
          child: Center(
            child: Lottie.asset(
              "assets/loading.json",
              repeat: true
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ); 
  }
```

How can I completely get rid of this LoadingBody widget with a cool fading animation after loading process is done and my base screen is already up? If I use something like a FutureBuilder or just setState, I can not set any transition animation so user has to see the glitchy creation of google map widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it with `Visibility` widget it will hide current widget with resource

```
Widget LoadingBody(){

return IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.loading ? false : true,
  child: AnimatedOpacity(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    opacity: loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.loading ? 1 : 0,
    child: Visibility(
      visible:  loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.loading,
      child: Container(
        color: chargeDarkGrey,
        child: Center(
            child: Lottie.asset(
                "assets/loading.json",
                repeat: true
            )
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Setting visible to false instantly removes the loading page, without any fade animation.

Comment: set visible property:  loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.loading, as mentioned in code above

Comment: I already did it like this, it evaluates to false when loadingStatus == LoadingStatus.loading is not true, so again animation is gone